# Meaning of dashboard "Check Engine Light" on motorbike

Tags: engine, motorcycle, cel, speedometer

Please help me understand the meaning of this dashboard light shown in the picture.

[ABOUT BIKE SPECIFICATION](http://autos.maxabout.com/bikes/yamaha/fazer-2010)

What happen if it blinks RED ?

[image: Check engine light motorbike]

Comment: What make and model of motorcycle is this?  I bet the blinking is manufacturer specific.

Comment: Please include your make/model/year.  There are hundreds if not thousands of different motorcycles over the years.  The blinking light on your make and model is specific to your bike.  If you would like to what your CEL (Check Engine Light) does please provide all the data about your bike and someone may be able to provide you with specific rather than generic information.

Comment: Also note that a "button" is specifically something that you can press that has a function.  If it's just a light, it's either called a "light" or "indicator"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the check engine light, or CEL - if it lights up, you have a problem with the engine and should stop and investigate it.

If it's blinking, count the number of flashes, as this will indicate a particular error code which can help you to determine what is wrong.

Comment: I thought on modern vehicles, a flashing CEL while driving meant the issue was actively occurring.  Like actively seeing a misfire rather than noticing a sensor isn't responding as expected.  Where I have seen the blinks indicate a code, you would have to initiate it by shorting pins, or turning the key 3 times.

Comment: in my case the light blinks and off after few minutes of riding...suppose i travel 100 km then in run of every 20km or 30 km its blinks. I read it shows engine oil level, but i have doubt that is it show heat up engine ?

Comment: @iphonemaclover The purpose of this light is for the vehicle to let you know it has detected a fault. It serves no other purpose than this. You need to get the bike checked out for what is wrong with it. If the light is on, the bike is broken.

Comment: @rpmerf, on a car, the blinking CEL indicates a misfire, and it blinks because that is more serious than other problems (it can damage other parts if not corrected).  On a bike, that doesn't have to support OBDII, its probably manufacturer specific.

Answer (score 1):

Just having the warning light come on only indicates a problem but not what the problem is or which sensor is being activated. This is really ridiculous. I stopped at a shop. They changed the oil. I stopped at another shop they added brake fluid. I was on a long drive up over the mountains to my home in northern Thailand. The light came on again, stopped at another shop. They shrugged their shoulders and said I should just try to make it home. I did but with great anxiety. I called a mechanic friend of mine and he gave me this advice. Hope this helps....
Have you checked the air filter? .
Check the coolant fluid reservoir.
It is behind the big front cover under the seat.
Also the same place as the air filter.
If low also remove the rad cover on the right side of the motor and check the coolant level in the radiator. Install coolant NOT water.
The most common thing is the speedo cable.
The computor uses the bikes speed in its calculations. If the speedo cable breaks or is about to brake which usualy causes the speedo to fluctuate the light will come on.
There is a simple code system that the bike uses.  You  simply watch turn on the key. If there is a problem, The yellow light will flash. If so, try turning on two or three times. You will start to see a pattern.
Example;
One short flash & 2 long
That would mean  #12
It is very rare to have codes come up on a Mio.
I no longer remember them.
But i got them on line.
Also check the oxigen sensor  conection.
Maybe try a new spark plug if not changed in the last year.
It is likely not a serious problem as these Yamahas are almost indestructable.
If the bike starts well and doesn t have any noises that is a good sign.
The Yamaha dealer will read the codes for free by watching the lights and tell you what it means.
Another small posibility is a bad wire connection at the speedo..
Good luck.
My problem was low cooling fluid in radiator. I didn't even know scooters had radiators.